JQuery text() function with multiple spaces
How can I display two consecutive spaces using the JQuery text() function?
Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/15d68fqh/1/
<span id="a2"></span>
$("#a2").text("first  second");


white-space:pre like this https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/soknjwL4/
